# With Square, can I capture less than I authorized

Tags: square, square-connect

When charging credit cards using the Square v2 REST API, I may have a need to sometimes capture less than was originally authorized. Mst CC gateways allow this, however a review of the Square v2 API shows Square may not support this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to capture less (or more) than was authorized. Depending on your specific use case you might be able to use card on file, authorize a transaction for an amount, and then void that authorization & charge for less than the initial amount when it comes time.

Comment: I did some testing and I see that I can not do this with a card nonce, since I need a second nonce for the new charge. However, it seems from the API docs that if I store the card with Square that I don't need a nonce. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, you do not need a card nonce to charge a card on file.

Comment: So then it would be a reasonable approach - from a technical standpoint -  to add the customer's card to Square, get its ID then authorize, complete the sale, and capture. If part of the sale failed then I could void the auth, and just then do a one step charge for the new amount? From a policy standpoint are there any policy or legal issues to adding the customer's card to Square without their consent? From a customer service standpoint that is problematic, but that's an issue I can handle.

Comment: You do need their consent to keep their card on file below is the disclaimer on Square's website. From a technical point of view, you would only need card on file for charges different than the auth amount.
_Do not link a card on file to a customer without the customer's express permission. For example, you can include a checkbox in your purchase flow (unchecked by default) that the customer can check to specify that they wish to save their card information for future purchases._